# Associative graded operation with non-neutral elements of size zero

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A=(A_0,A_1,\dots)$ be a graded set with $A_k$ finite for all $k$, i.e. the elements in $A_k$ are the elements of size $k$. Is there an associative operation $*$ which is graded, i.e.
$$ *: A_k\times A_\ell\to A_{k+\ell}, $$
such that there is an element of size $0$ that is not a neutral element?

Comment: What is the "size" of an element?

Comment: I edited the question, for example $A$ is the set of all permutations, then $A_k$ are all permutations of size $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little weird since we know nothing about the set, but if all you want is associativity then yes it is possible, if and only if:

- the subset $M\subset \mathbb{N}$ of indices $k$ such that $A_k\neq \emptyset$ is a submonoid of $\mathbb{N}$;
- not all $A_k$ with $k\in M$ have cardinality $1$.

I'll let you check that the conditions are necessary (the second one is needed so that there is a non-neutral element in $A_0$; if it is not satisfied then $A$ must be isomorphic to $M$ as a monoid).

If they are satisfied, then choose an element $a_k\in A_k$ for all $k\in M$, and define $x\ast y=a_{k+l}$ for all $x\in A_k$ and $y\in A_l$.